# On the locality of the Lefschetz conditions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Given a smooth projective variety $X$ of dimension $\geq 3$ and an ample divisor $Y$. The pair satisfy the effective Lefschetz condition $Leff(X,Y)$. This implies that the category of vector bundles on a neighborhood of $Y$ is equivalent to the category of vector bundles on the formal completion $\hat{X}_Y$. Now given an open $U$ that does NOT necessarily contain $Y$ and a vector bundle $E$ on $X$. Can we extend any section of $E|_{\hat{U}_{U\cap Y}}$ to $E|_U$? If not are there any obstructions?

Comment: "the vector bundle can be uniquely extended to the whole $X$": that's not true.

Comment: You are right,extension exists as a unique coherent sheaf not necessarily a vector bundle.

Comment: You need that $X$ has dimension at least 3, not 2.